# Fallo al comprobar si un vector se encuentra dentro de una matriz

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en Java para comprobar si un vector se encuentra dentro de una matriz. En caso de que la primera posición del vector coincida con la actual de la matriz, saltaré a la siguiente posición del vector para seguir la comprobación. Mi problema viene a la hora de saltar de fila en la matriz y a establecer la posición del vector a 0. No se como establecer dicha condición.

```
public static PosicionMatriz buscaVectorEnMatriz(int[][] matriz, int[] vector) {


    int coincidencia = 0;
    int avance  = 0;
    PosicionMatriz pm;
    int columna = 0;
    int fila = 0;


    vector = new int[3];
    vector[0] = 3;
    vector[1] = 5;
    vector[2] = 6;

    matriz = new int[3][3];
    matriz[0][0] = 1;
    matriz[0][1] = 5;
    matriz[0][2] = 3;
    matriz[1][0] = 3;
    matriz[1][1] = 5;
    matriz[1][2] = 6;
    matriz[2][0] = 2;
    matriz[2][1] = 9;
    matriz[2][2] = 0;



    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) { // recorre el eje de la y
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {// recorre el eje de la x
            for (int k = 0; k < vector.length; k++) { // recorre el vector

                if (vector.length > matriz[i].length) { // Si longitud de vector > que longitud de la fila pasa a la siguiente
                    coincidencia = 0;
                    i++; // Saltamos de fila
                }

                if (vector[k] == matriz[i][j]) {
                    coincidencia++;
                    System.out.println("Se ha encontrado la coincidencia en " + "[" + (i) + "]" + "[" + (j) + "]");

                } else {
                    k = 0; // Reestablecemos la posición del vector a la primera si no coincide con la de la matriz
                    coincidencia = 0;

                }

                if(coincidencia == vector.length) {
                    System.out.println("Finaliza la búsqueda");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Declarar el vector y la matriz, y asignarle valores, debería estar fuera de la función, y luego pasar esas variables como parámetros. Es decir que no forman parte de la función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el comentario que has dejado en la otra respuesta:

> Desarrolle, un método llamado `buscaVectorEnMatriz()` que tiene como parámetros una matriz y un vector. El método realiza la búsqueda del vector en la matriz y devuelve la posición de la primera ocurrencia donde hubo una coincidencia. Si no se encuentra el vector en la matriz el método devuelve `null`. El vector solo se debe buscar por filas. Cada fila de la matriz puede tener una longitud distinta.

Debo decir que la solución es muy sencilla, no es necesario comparar cada elemento del vector, solo hay que comparar si la fila corresponde al mismo objeto.

Lo que trata de hacer la función es devolver la posición donde está el vector. Cada fila es un número entero que significa la posición de memoria de dicha *fila*, y puede ser comparado con el entero del *vector* ingresado en la función.

Para devolver `null`, cambio `void` por `Integer`, y dentro del `for`, devuelvo el `int` convertido a `Integer`.

Solución:

```
public Integer buscaVectorEnMatriz(int[][] matriz, int[] vector)
{
    for (int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++)
    {
        if(matriz[i]==vector){return new Integer(i);}
    }
    return null;
}
```

Si lo que se quiere es comparar cada elemento de la fila, para saber si es la misma fila, primero hay que comprobar que la longitud de la fila sea igual que la longitud del vector ingresado. En caso contrario, comparar los elementos, uno por uno.

```
public Integer buscaVectorEnMatriz(int[][] matriz, int[] vector)
{
    for (int i=0;i<matriz.length;i++)
    {
        if(matriz[i].length==vector.length)
        {
            boolean es_igual=true;
            for (int j=0;j<matriz[i].length;j++)
            {
                if(matriz[i][j]!=vector[j])
                {
                    es_igual=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(es_igual)
            {
                return new Integer(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

En realidad tu problema es que la lógica de tu algoritmo esta mal.

Tu algoritmo en realidad no sabe si una fila de la matriz es igual al vector, porque solo busca posicionalmente, y lo que pasa en la primera fila de la matriz es el claro ejemplo de porque no funciona.. fíjate que la fila 1/5/3 deja posactual en 1.. porque?? porque busca la coincidencia de la siguiente manera:

- compara 3 con 1, le da falso, deja posactual en 0 (y aquí ya esta mal, en realidad ni siquiera deberías seguir mirando esta fila)
- compara 3 con 5, le da falso, mismo caso que arriba
- compara 3 con 3, le da verdadero, deja posactual en 1.

Para que se entienda, posactual ni debería existir, puesto que posactual, debería tener el mismo valor que j, ya que son la misma posición a comparar.

Eso igual te deja con otro problema, como saber si toda la fila es exactamente igual.. para eso puedes usar un contador para cada vez que encuentras una coincidencia, ir sumándole uno. y al terminar la fila (al salir del `for(j)`) podrías verificar si ese contador mide lo mismo que el vector. y si son iguales, esa fila es la que te sirve. si no, solamente pones el contador a 0, y sigues con la fila que sigue.

Como es un ejercicio, te dejo la tarea de arreglarlo, pero ya sabes donde estan los problemas.

Comment: La lógica de usar la misma variable para las filas y para el vector está bien pensada pero el vector no debe avanzar a la vez que la fila de la matriz. Es decir, si la primera posición de la fila no coincide con la primera del vector, el vector mantiene la primera posición y no avanza  para compararla con la segunda de la matriz por lo que usar la misma variable no me vale en este caso.

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario. Si la fila de la matriz no es igual al vector no importa a dode apunte.. o no estas buscando eso, estas buscando otra cosa? Tal vez la pregunta no es clara? Por eso a vecea un ejemplo de lo que queres esta bien

Comment: Tienes razón, quizás no me haya explicado bien. Obviando detalles, este es el enunciado que me proporcionan : Desarrolle, un método llamado buscaVectorEnMatriz() que tiene como parámetros una matriz y un vector. El método realiza la búsqueda del vector en la matriz y devuelve la posición de la primera ocurrencia donde hubo una coincidencia. Si no se encuentra el vector en la matriz el método devuelve null. El vector solo se debe buscar por filas. Cada fila de la matriz puede tener una longitud distinta. Por esto último, no puedo avanzar  con la misma variable en la fila que en el vector.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta con eso.. y entonces si la respuesta es un poco diferente ya que el algoritmo es diferente y se parece un poco mas al que mostraste vos...

Comment: y si cada fila de la matriz puede tener una dimension variable, entonces no tienes una matriz.. tienes un vector de vectores.. no deberias definirlo asi ni manejarlo asi...

Comment: Ese es mi problema, no se como se maneja de manera correcta la matriz mediante los bucles for. Ese es el código que tengo hasta el momento pero al restablecer la posición del vector a 0 me entra en un bucle infinito.

Comment: espera.. cambiaste todo el codigo de la pregunta??? mi respuesta ya es totalmente invalida.. no deberias hacer eso.. o aceptabas una respuesta, y abrias otra pregunta, o editabas la pregunta y agregabas lo nuevo.. o no se.. en realidad deberia borrar esta respuesta, pq ya no contesta tu pregunta...

Comment: Una pista muy importante @AGeekM. En Java, una matriz es en realidad un arreglo de arreglos (o vector de vectores, si quieres usar esa palabra). Entonces, podrías tener dos métodos: 1) `public int buscaIgualdad(int[] vectorABuscar, int[] vectorDondeBuscar)` y devuelve la posición en la que comienza esa igualdad, 2) `public int buscaVectorEnMatriz(int[][] matriz, int[] vector) { for (int i = 0, i < matriz.length; i++) { buscaIgualdad(matriz[i], vector); } }` (es la base del código no voy a hacerlo todo ;) )